# Rows Into Columns and Grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT OrganizationName, OrganizationID, ReceivableStatus, InvoiceFee
FROM v_InvoicesFreelanceOutstanding
ORDER BY OrganizationID
```

The data from that might look like this:

```
OrganizationName    OrganizationID        ReceivableStatus       InvoiceFee
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Company A                      139        60-90 days                 672.00
Company A                      139        60-90 days                1800.00
Company A                      139        over 90 days              1440.00
Company B                      264        Current                   3559.38
Company B                      264        60-90 days                3785.50
Company C                      271        60-90 days                 446.25
Company C                      271        over 90 days               637.50
Company C                      271        over 90 days              1126.25
```

What I want to eventually display is something like this (for the data above):

```
Company     Current    30-60 days    60-90 days    over 90 days       Total   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Company A         0             0       2472.00               0     2472.00
Company B   3559.38             0       3785.50               0     7344.88
Company C         0             0        446.25         1763.75     2210.00
```

My SQL-fu is not enough to get me past this:

```
SELECT
    MAX(OrganizationName) as OrganizationName,
    OrganizationID,
    ReceivableStatus,
    SUM(InvoiceFee) as TotalDue
FROM v_InvoicesFreelanceOutstanding
GROUP BY OrganizationID, ReceivableStatus
```

Which shows something like this (again, from the data above):

```
OrganizationName    OrganizationID        ReceivableStatus         TotalDue
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Company A                      139        60-90 days                2472.00
Company A                      139        over 90 days              1440.00
Company B                      264        Current                   3559.38
Company B                      264        60-90 days                3785.50
Company C                      271        60-90 days                 446.25
Company C                      271        over 90 days              1763.75
```

What then? Any help would be appreciated.

Note that the statuses shown in the 2nd table (`Current`, `30-60 days`, `60-90 days`, `over 90 days`) are the only ones I'm expecting to come up under `ReceivableStatus`.

**EDIT**: Sorry for not including this. I am aware of `PIVOT` but I couldn't get it to do what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a job for [`pivot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) if you're using SQL Server 2005 or later.

EDIT:

Since you already know about `pivot`, you know it does almost what you need.

You already have the following query:

```
SELECT
    MAX(OrganizationName) as OrganizationName,
    OrganizationID,
    ReceivableStatus,
    SUM(InvoiceFee) as TotalDue
FROM v_InvoicesFreelanceOutstanding
GROUP BY OrganizationID, ReceivableStatus
```

Which gives you the current, 30-60, 60-90 and 90+ parts that you need. If you pivot that, you get everything you need except for your total. So just throw in the total:

```
(SELECT
    MAX(OrganizationName) as OrganizationName,
    OrganizationID,
    ReceivableStatus,
    SUM(InvoiceFee) as TotalDue
FROM v_InvoicesFreelanceOutstanding
GROUP BY OrganizationID, ReceivableStatus)
UNION
(SELECT
    MAX(OrganizationName) as OrganizationName,
    OrganizationID,
    'Total' AS ReceivableStatus,
    SUM(InvoiceFee) as TotalDue
FROM v_InvoicesFreelanceOutstanding
GROUP BY OrganizationID)
```

Pivot on this result and you should get the output you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    [the query above]
PIVOT (
    SUM(TotalDue)
    FOR ReceivableStatus IN ([Current],[30-60 days],[60-90 days],[over 90 days],[Total]) 
)
```

Comment: I should have been clearer; I am aware of PIVOT, I was just unable to make it do what I need.

Comment: I'm a moron. My first go at the PIVOT is what you have but I did SUM(InvoiceFee) instead of SUM(TotalDue) in the PIVOT clause. Boohoo. It works, though. Thank you.

Comment: We all make mistakes. The important thing is we learn from them. I'm just glad I could help.

Answer (score 8):

PIVOT sucks. It has horrible syntax and isn't a PIVOT in the pivot table sense i.e. you have to know exactly how many columns will result in advance.

It's probably easier to do a cross-tab report.

```
SELECT 
OrganizationName,
OrganizationID,
SUM(CASE WHEN ReceivableStatus       = '30-60 days' THEN InvoiceFee ELSE 0 END) AS [30 - 60 Days],
SUM(CASE WHEN ReceivableStatus       = '60-90 days' THEN InvoiceFee ELSE 0 END) AS [60 - 90 Days],
SUM(CASE WHEN ReceivableStatus       = '90-120 days' THEN InvoiceFee ELSE 0 END) AS [90 - 120 Days]

FROM
v_InvoicesFreelanceOutstanding
GROUP BY OrganizationID
```

Comment: How would this work with the GROUP, though? I only want to show the SUM(InvoiceFee) of 30-60 days under the 30-60 days column, and so on.

Comment: And I will know how many columns will result in advance, so I am okay with PIVOT if it will get the job done, although the syntax is making my head hurt.

Comment: `COUNTIF()` is a cleaner and better way to do `SUM(CASE())`

Answer (score 2):

I have not used pivot before, so that may be your answer, but I've used brute force on a problem like this in the past and for you it would look something like:

```
SELECT OrganizationName, SUM(Current) AS Current, SUM(3060Days) AS 3060Days, SUM(6090Days) AS 6090Days, SUM(Over90Days) As Over90Days, SUM(Total) AS Total
FROM 
(
SELECT 
    OrganizationName,
    CASE WHEN ReceivableStatus = 'Current' THEN
        SUM(InvoiceFee)
    ELSE
        0
    END AS Current,
    CASE WHEN ReceivableStatus = '30-60 days' THEN
        SUM(InvoiceFee)
    ELSE
        0
    END AS 3060Days,
    CASE WHEN ReceivableStatus = '60-90 days' THEN
        SUM(InvoiceFee)
    ELSE
        0
    END AS 6090Days,
    CASE WHEN ReceivableStatus = 'over 90 days' THEN
        SUM(InvoiceFee)
    ELSE
        0
    END AS Over90Days,
    SUM(InvoiceFee) AS Total
FROM v_InvoicesFreelanceOutstanding
GROUP BY OrganizationName, ReceivableStatus) temp
GROUP BY OrganizationName
```

Basically, the inner query gives you results for each organization and a total for each individual category and the outer query aggregates all of them into single rows for each organization.  Again, this may not be the most elegant or efficient way to go, but it is a way.

Comment: +1. Although it worked, it is bigger than I was hoping and I got the PIVOT working. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 2):

Well, here is another pivot :)

```sql
SET NOCOUNT ON
    
DECLARE @table TABLE
(   OrganizationName    VARCHAR(20),
    OrganizationID      INT,
    ReceivableStatus    VARCHAR(20),
    InvoiceFee      FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO @table
SELECT 'Company A',139,'60-90 days',672.00 UNION
SELECT 'Company A',139,'60-90 days',1800.00 UNION
SELECT 'Company A',139,'over 90 days',1440.00 UNION
SELECT 'Company B',264,'Current',3559.38 UNION
SELECT 'Company B',264,'60-90 days',3785.50 UNION
SELECT 'Company C',271,'60-90 days',446.25 UNION
SELECT 'Company C',271,'over 90 days',637.50 UNION
SELECT 'Company C',271,'over 90 days',1126.25

--Specify Just the fields you want to return
;WITH COMPANYINFO(OrganizationName,OrganizationID,ReceivableStatus,InvoiceFee) AS
    (
    SELECT  OrganizationName,
        OrganizationID,
        ReceivableStatus,
        InvoiceFee
    FROM    @Table AS b 
    )
    SELECT * 
    FROM COMPANYINFO
    PIVOT
        (
        SUM(InvoiceFee)
        FOR ReceivableStatus
        IN ([Current],[60-90 days],[over 90 days])
        )
    AS P
    ORDER BY OrganizationName
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your are searching for the pivot and unpivot functionality.
Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

Comment: I should have been clearer; I am aware of PIVOT, I was just unable to make it do what I need.