# Grouping into columns: How to generate SUM(CASE ... columns in the query rather than copy pasting once for each case?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, pivot

I'm trying to do a "group into columns" kind of query. The relevant answers I've found use a format like this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/666442):

```sql
SELECT 
OrganizationName,
OrganizationID,
SUM(CASE WHEN ReceivableStatus       = '30-60 days' THEN InvoiceFee ELSE 0 END) AS [30 - 60 Days],
SUM(CASE WHEN ReceivableStatus       = '60-90 days' THEN InvoiceFee ELSE 0 END) AS [60 - 90 Days],
SUM(CASE WHEN ReceivableStatus       = '90-120 days' THEN InvoiceFee ELSE 0 END) AS [90 - 120 Days]

FROM
v_InvoicesFreelanceOutstanding
GROUP BY OrganizationID
```

So there, you're kind of grouping the data into 3 columns, using case to pick selectively from each one. But what if you have, say, 100 cases (in a different context)? Surely the solution isn't just to copy and paste that `SUM(CASE...` line 100 times with different conditions for each column? Is there a way to hook in something like `generate_series` to programmatically generate the columns?

A clearer example:

Say I have this data:

```
+---------+-------------+---------------------+
| User ID | Account Age | Active After X Days |
+---------+-------------+---------------------+
| A       |           2 |                   0 |
| A       |           2 |                   1 |
| A       |           2 |                   2 |
| B       |           2 |                   0 |
| B       |           2 |                   1 |
| C       |           3 |                   0 |
| C       |           3 |                   1 |
| C       |           3 |                   2 |
+---------+-------------+---------------------+
```

Where each row represents 1 user whose account is "Account Age" days old (at the time of the query) having done some action after X days. Each user can appear once per day of their account's lifetime.

I would like to be able to output something like:

```
+---------------------+-----------+------------+------------+
| Active After X Days | 1 Day Old | 2 Days Old | 3 Days Old |
+---------------------+-----------+------------+------------+
|                   0 |         0 |          2 |          1 |
|                   1 |         0 |          2 |          1 |
|                   2 |         0 |          1 |          1 |
|                   3 |         0 |          0 |          0 |
|                   4 |         0 |          0 |          0 |
|                   5 |         0 |          0 |          0 |
+---------------------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

but without having to manually list out 1, 2, 3 days old OR the active after X days, instead being able to specify in the query somewhere that I want activity after 0-5 days and accounts 1-3 days old. This being the case, flipping the axes is fine too.

In other words, effectively having it be more like a traditional non-SQL 2d table where it might be drawn like so with two axes:

```
+---------------------+-----------+------------+------------+
|                     | 1 Day Old | 2 Days Old | 3 Days Old |
+---------------------+-----------+------------+------------+
| Active After X Days |                                     |
+---------------------+-----------+------------+------------+
|                   0 |         0 |          2 |          1 |
|                   1 |         0 |          2 |          1 |
|                   2 |         0 |          1 |          1 |
|                   3 |         0 |          0 |          0 |
|                   4 |         0 |          0 |          0 |
|                   5 |         0 |          0 |          0 |
+---------------------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

I just want to visually the data in this way, but I'm not sure that it's possible.

Comment: It's unclear to me what exactly the output is you want (also: the query you have shown is invalid for Postgres).  Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Doing a pivot/crosstab (which is what that statement is doing) **is** going to require to list each column separately. You can't have "dynamic columns" in SQL where the columns are determined during the runtime of the query that shows those columns. If you need that to be dynamic, return the groups as rows, not columns.

Comment: Your only option is to use dynamic SQL where you create the 100 column query, then run it.

Comment: Thanks for the info @a_horse_with_no_name, I updated the post with a more detailed example input/output, though it sounds like it's probably not possible.

Comment: Thanks @TomC, hadn't heard of dynamic SQL before and will look into it now.